# How to iterate through years and weeks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I access weeks thanks to a route defined like so :

```
get 'missions/:year/:week' => 'missions#index'
```

I want to display the week and 2 links to go to the previous week and to the next one.

We need to know in which year is the next week. 'cweek' is giving me the correct week number but I need to know the year.

It seems that getting the year of the next thursday is working but this is kind of ugly. Here is my what I do in the missions#index action so that I can have the correct urls then :

```
@week = params[:week]
@year = params[:year]

@start_date = Date.commercial(@year.to_i, @week.to_i)

# To navigate between weeks
@prev_week = (@start_date - 1.week).cweek
@prev_year = (@start_date - 1.week + 4.days).year

@next_week = (@start_date + 1.week).cweek
@next_year = (@start_date + 1.week + 4.days).year
```

Any idea how to do this better ?

Comment: for me your question is so confusing.. Can you tell what you want, so that I can think of my way..

Comment: What's next thursday got to do with anything?

Comment: @ArupRakshit When accessing /missions/2014/26 I want 2 links on this page to go to /missions/2014/25 and /missions/2014/27. Problem is on the end and the beginning of a new year.

Comment: @MaxWilliams It is important to note that weeks are starting on monday for me and that start_date is always a monday. That being said here is an example : If I'm on the 52nd weeks of 2014 and I want to go to the next week. If I only add 1week to get the year I will go to 2014/1 instead of 2015/1 because for the date 2014-12-29 the year is 2014 but it's the week number 1 (commercial weeks).

Comment: @MaxWilliams The first week according to ISO 8601 is defined to be that week with the first thursday of the year. Thus, the train of thought isn't that far fetched.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct year to the week number returned by `Date#cweek` is returned by [`Date#cwyear`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-cwyear). As such, this method makes it a primary candidate for using it with `cweek`.

```
# To navigate between weeks
@prev_week = (@start_date - 1.week).cweek
@prev_year = (@start_date - 1.week).cwyear

@next_week = (@start_date + 1.week).cweek
@next_year = (@start_date + 1.week).cwyear
```

Answer (score -1):

If i was you i would deal with actual times as much as possible, ie set your instance variables to be date/time objects:

```
@prev_week = @start_date - 1.week
@prev_year = @start_date - 1.year

@next_week = @start_date + 1.week
@next_year = @start_date + 1.year
```

then in the actual links themselves, on the page:

```
<%= link_to "Next week", missions_path(:week => @next_week.week, :year => @next_year.year) %>
```

etc

Comment: There is no `#week` on the Date class. Also, your `@next_year` doesn't make sense for OP, as it shouldn't literally be the date of today next year but instead be the year of next week. And finally: OP already uses actual `Date` objects where it makes sense.